# Rolling a D6 and getting consecutive rolls that differ by 1

Tags: probability

I roll a six-sided die 200 times. What is the expected number of occasions on which
I will see two consecutive rolls that differ by 1?
For example, a sequence 1334546 would count as 3 such consecutive pairs.
The solution said that the probability of getting a single pair of this form is $\frac{10}{36} = \frac{5}{18}.$ I dont understand how this is obtained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ten is '1 followed by 2'.  Find the others and count them.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! I was thinking the probability was 1/3 since every number had 2 other numbers that differ by 1 (completely forgot abt 1 and 6)